# Conditional to \begin and \end some environment

Tags: environments, conditionals

The conditional structure of the macro of the MWE allow print two text strings as "`true`" and "`false`" alternatively. So you can print something like "`false true false true false true`" calling six times the same macro without any option.

But if the printed strings made a environment (that is: `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`) this works only the first time, as in the MWE. With a second  `\tin  .... \tin` then `pdflatex` said that *`\begin{document}` is ended by `\end{...}`*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\iftiny
\def\tin{\iftiny
\tinyfalse \end{tiny}
\else
\tinytrue \begin{tiny} 
\fi}
\begin{document}
 normal size 
\tin tiny size \tin normal size
% uncomment the next line to see the problem 
% \tin tiny size \tin normal size   
\end{document}
```

- What happen with the second `\begin{tiny}` when the macro is called four times?
- Why is wrong this code?
- How fix this problem?

Comment: Beware that `\begin` starts a group and `\end` closes it, so assignments such as `\tinyfalse` made inside them disappear.

Comment: @egreg. That is. Then moving `\tinyfalse` before of `\begin` and `\tinytrue` after `\begin` solved the problem! Please, make an  answer to accept it.

Comment: A condition like `iftiny` can be defined without `\newif`. Something like `\let\iftiny\iffalse` and your definition of `\tinytrue` can be `\def\tinytrue{\global\let\iftiny\iftrue}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every `\begin` command issues `\begingroup`, which corresponds to a command `\endgroup` issued by `\end`.

Assignments such as `\tinyfalse` or `\tinytrue` are local to the group in which they appear. You can do `\global\tinytrue` and `\global\tinyfalse` if you want that the assignment transcends the group it's performed in.

Let's see what happens with your code.

```
\tin tiny size \tin normal size
```

becomes

```
\iftiny\tinyfalse\end{tiny}\else\tinytrue\begin{tiny}\fi tiny size \tin normal size
```

Since a conditional is initially false, the true branch is skipped and

```
\tinytrue\begin{tiny}\fi tiny size \tin normal size
```

remains. The assignment is performed, the `tiny` environment is started with its `\begingroup` and `tiny` size is printed (`\fi` disappears because of its working). Now remember we are in a group; when `\tin` is found it's expanded and we're confronted with

```
\iftiny\tinyfalse\end{tiny}\else\tinytrue\begin{tiny}\fi normal size
```

Now `\iftiny` follows the true branch and the resulting token list is

```
\tinyfalse\end{tiny}\else\tinytrue\begin{tiny}\fi normal size
```

The assignment is performed, then `\end{tiny}` is executed with its `\endgroup` that undoes the assignment made by `\tinyfalse` and so `\iftiny` remains true. The `\else...\fi` part disappears and `normal size` is printed.

If now you execute again the input

```
\tin tiny size \tin normal size
```

you're starting with `\iftiny` returning true! So

```
\iftiny\tinyfalse\end{tiny}\else\tinytrue\begin{tiny}\fi tiny size \tin normal size
```

follows the true branch, giving

```
\tinyfalse\end{tiny}\else\tinytrue\begin{tiny}\fi tiny size \tin normal size
```

and there's an `\end{tiny}` that doesn't belong there.

Comment: In this case the offending command is only `\tinyfalse`, therefore  `\global\tinyfalse` or move it after `\end{tiny}` was enough. Grazie mile.

Comment: @Fran I've added an analysis of what happens

Answer (score 3):

Besides the explanation of egreg here another approach defining your conditional:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\iftiny\iffalse
\def\tinytrue{\global\let\iftiny\iftrue}
\def\tinyfalse{\global\let\iftiny\iffalse}
\def\tin{\iftiny\tinyfalse\end{tiny}\else\tinytrue\begin{tiny}\fi}
\begin{document}
 normal size 
\tin tiny size \tin normal size
 uncomment the next line to see the problem 
 \tin tiny size \tin normal size   
\end{document}
```

---

The op wrote that this solution isn't such intuitive. So I think a small explanation about `\newif` is necessary.

The command `\newif` is defined in the LaTeX-kernel in the following

```
\def\newif#1{%
  \count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
    \let#1\iffalse
    \@if#1\iftrue
    \@if#1\iffalse
  \escapechar\count@}
```

This really clever definition does three things. First it defines a new command which is equal to `\iffalse` by `\let#1\iffalse`. This is equal to the example above.

The next two lines are calling the macro `\@if` with the following definition:

```
\def\@if#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#1%
                    \expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#2\endcsname
                       {\let#1#2}}
```

In short it gobbles the first two tokens of the input string one and two e.g. from `\iftiny` you get `tiny` and from `\iffalse` you get `false`. In the next step you get the definition: `\def\tinyfalse{\let\iftiny\iffalse}`. The solution above does nearly the same but it add a `\global` assignment.

Comment: +1 Is less intuitive (for me) how it works, but it works. :-)

Comment: @Fran: I added a small explanation. I hope it's now more intuitive ;-)

Comment: Intuitive could be a nipple for a baby, a `\color{red}` command for me, the Matrix code for Neo, or a sequence of TeX primitives for you, but I am not still at that level.  Please do not misunderstand this comment as some disagreement because the answer is not for dummies. I really appreciate your explanation.`:-)`

Comment: @Fran: I understand your comment ;-)